Trying to setup Eclipse/PyDev to debug application that must run as root
I want to use Eclipse/PyDev to debug an application that must run as root. I found this: Debugging project with root in PyDev/LiClipse and followed the instructions in answer #2, but ran into problems. In particular when I tried to set the interpreter for the project to the specified script (see below), Eclipse threw an error.
Here is the setup:
dnessett@homelserv:~$ cd SaltSource/
dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource$ cd scripts/
dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource/scripts$ ls -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 dnessett dnessett 4096 Oct  1 13:51 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 dnessett dnessett 4096 Oct  1 13:49 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dnessett dnessett   29 Oct  1 13:51 python_on_root.sh
dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource/scripts$
dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource/scripts$ cat python_on_root.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo python "$@"

dnessett@homelserv:/etc$ sudo cat sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"
Defaults    use_pty

...

#add python to sudo list
dnessett homelserv=(root)NOPASSWD:/home/dnessett/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "@include" directives:

@includedir /etc/sudoers.d


Note that I modified the sudoers file so the entry was bound to the machine name rather than "ALL".
When I tried to add the script to the project interpreters list,

I got the following error message:

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The use of a script that sudo's a python interpreter does not work. Eclipse/PyDev will not accept it. However, I found another way to accomplish this. Using pyenv to select a particular python interpreter for the project, I drill down into the path where that interpreter resides. I then change it to root ownership and turn on the setuid bit. I then supply this python interpreter path to Eclipse/PyDev and it accepts it. You have to soft link .pydev to dotpydev, since the Eclipse/PyDev interpreter selection protocol does not list dot files.
I am still testing this approach and will post a comment if it succeeds (and post a comment if it doesn't). Right now the test is stuck on Eclipse/PyDev not finding a module that is necessary for the application. I am posting this problem in another thread, since it is not directly related to running python code as root in projects
After testing, it became clear that changing the owner of the project python to root before executing python -m pip install -e . causes problems. So the correct sequence is: 1) install a version of python to use for the project (pyenv install <version>), 2) runpython -m pip install -e . and 3) THEN change the owner of the python version to root and set its setuid bit.
For example, if the version of python to use for the project is 3.10.15, first execute pydev install 3.10.15 and associate it with the project (cd to project source directory and execute pydev local 3.10.15), then in the project source directory execute python -m pip install -e ., THEN drill down to where the python executable lives (e.g., /home/dnessett/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin) and change the executable so it is owned by root and has its setuid bit set (e.g., -rwsr-xr-x 1 root     root     17656 Sep 22 18:07 python3.10
