Eclipse/PyDev not finding installed packages
I am attempting to run a Python application from Eclipse/PyDev, but am encountering an error that seems to have something to do with PYTHONPATH. When I list the installed packages for python using pip, I get:
pip list
Package            Version               Editable project location
------------------ --------------------- -------------------------------------
certifi            2024.8.30
charset-normalizer 3.4.0
contextvars        2.4
croniter           3.0.3
distro             1.9.0
idna               3.10
immutables         0.21
Jinja2             3.1.4
jmespath           1.0.1
looseversion       1.3.0
MarkupSafe         3.0.1
msgpack            1.1.0
packaging          24.1
pip                23.0.1
psutil             6.0.0
pycryptodomex      3.21.0
pydevd             3.1.0
python-dateutil    2.9.0.post0
pytz               2024.2
PyYAML             6.0.2
pyzmq              26.2.0
requests           2.32.3
salt               3006.9+98.g0dc964fb50 /home/dnessett/SaltSource/3006.9/salt
setuptools         65.5.0
six                1.16.0
urllib3            2.2.3

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

However, when I run this application within Eclipse/PyDev, I get the following error traceback (the first part of this text block is the text of the application):
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
This script is used to kick off a salt minion daemon
"""

from multiprocessing import freeze_support

import salt.utils.platform
from salt.scripts import salt_minion

if __name__ == "__main__":
if salt.utils.platform.is_windows():
# Since this file does not have a '.py' extension, when running on
# Windows, spawning any addional processes will fail due to Python
# not being able to load this 'module' in the new process.
# Work around this by creating a '.pyc' file which will enable the
# spawned process to load this 'module' and proceed.
import os.path
import py_compile

cfile = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0] + ".pyc"
if not os.path.exists(cfile):
py_compile.compile(__file__, cfile)
# This handles the bootstrapping code that is included with frozen
# scripts. It is a no-op on unfrozen code.
freeze_support()
salt_minion()

========================

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dnessett/SaltSource/3006.9/salt/scripts/salt-minion", line 8, in <module>
import salt.utils.platform
File "/home/dnessett/SaltSource/3006.9/salt/salt/utils/platform.py", line 12, in <module>
import distro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'
[ERROR ] An un-handled exception was caught by Salt's global exception handler:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/dnessett/SaltSource/3006.9/salt/scripts/salt-minion", line 8, in <module>
import salt.utils.platform
File "/home/dnessett/SaltSource/3006.9/salt/salt/utils/platform.py", line 12, in <module>
import distro
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distro'

Eclipse/PyDev is reporting that it cannot find the module 'distro'. But that module is in the list given by pip of installed modules (5th item down in that list). Do I have to modify the PYTHONPATH information to include installed modules? If so, how do I do that?
I created this by cloning into ~/SaltSource/3006.9:
git clone https://github.com/dnessett/salt

I selected the 3006.x tag by:
git switch -t origin/3006.x

I then selected 3006.9:
git checkout tags/v3006.9

I then installed this source using:
python -m pip install -e .

I then associated a python interpreter with the installed source using:
sudo pyenv local 3.10.15

The version of pip associated with the source is:
dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource/3006.9$ which pip
/home/dnessett/.pyenv/shims/pip

dnessett@homelserv:~/SaltSource/3006.9$ pip --version
pip 22.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)

This is all in support of running python as root under Eclipse/PyDev. This is necessary to allow Eclipse/PyDev to debug applications that run as root. For a full explanation of this requirement, see: Stack Overflow thread

Are you using a venv or similar? Can you show the configuration for in in PyDev?

I use pyenv to associate a python interpreter with a source directory. Here are images of the windows that pertain to PYTHONPATH. Eclipse/PyDev setup windows

Please [edit] your question and include how exactly you installed the dependencies before (via a venv, a package manager like conda, in your global environment, etc). Please also include where pip is located (which pip on Linux/MacOS or where pip on Windows).

I have done as you requested and edited my original question to show how I installed the application I am attempting to use.

This problem arises from using a different version of python to pip install source rather than the version that is owned by root and has its setuid bit set. It comes from not understanding what python -m pip install -e . does, which is to set up the dependencies for the version of python used by the source in a directory (in the example, ~/SaltSource/3006.9/salt). The solution is to install the version of python which will be used for the source, run python -m pip install -e . and THEN change the owner/group of the installed python version (in the case of the example given, ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin/python3.10) to root and set its setuid bit. As mentioned by @dan1st, the original question did not mention the fact that the python version must run as root, so I am amending it to make this clear.

In the image you shared, you have configured some Python interpreter:

However, your Python environment is located in /home/dnessett/.pyenv/shims. Knowing this, click the New button in the Python interpreters view and select /home/dnessett/.pyenv/shims/python.
This should then use the same environment.

I don't believe this will achieve the objective I am seeking. The interpreter I have currently selected executes as root. The permissions on .../python3.10 have root as the owner and its setuid bit set. This is the only way I have found to get Eclipse/PyDev to execute a python application as root (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79044714/trying-to-setup-eclipse-pydev-to-debug-application-that-must-run-as-root). Providing a bash script with an embedded "sudo python" does not work. Is there any way to include the Python environment without changing the python interpreter?

I don't know about your environment but venvs are typically symlinks to the actual python executable. In any way, when you were running pip list you weren't running it with that executable so you got different packages. If you tried to run that .../python3.10 (or respective pip) executable, you would probably not get these packages.

In any way, I don't see you including information about that root issue in your question. Please clarify what you are running as root in what way. It might be possible to use the same setuid configuration on the python environment with the dependencies.

You are correct. I did not mention the need for a rooted version of python in my original post. I thought that might complicate the question and lead to confusion. However, if you look at the Stack Overflow post (see the link I provided in my first comment), you will see that I need a version of python that runs as root. This is so I can use Eclipse/PyDev to debug an application that runs as root. Duplicating the information provided in that post would take a lot of space and would take us off topic.

I am beginning to see the problem. python3.10.15 is owned by root. When I installed the git source, I used python3.10.14 (i.e., I executed pyenv local 3.10.14 and then python -m pip install -e .), since using python3.10.15 would run python as root and I was concerned that any files generated would be owned by root (and therefore not accessible to Eclipse/PyDev). So, the installation had no effect on ~/.pyenv/versions/3.10.15/bin. So, the question now is should I create python3.10.15, run the installation and then change python3.10.15 to root and setuid it?

I don't know why you have to work with setuid from.a Python script (this seems very dangerous as any Python script could be run with the suid interpreter). But I think you should have one consistent environment with what's necessary and use that in PyDev as well.

dan1st: thank you for your help. With your comments and answer I was able to figure out the problem and provide an answer to the question. In regards to why the solution requires setting the local python interpreter ownership to root and setting its setuid bit, see the answer I have provided. This is the only way I have found to allow Eclipse/PyDev to debug applications that run as root.
